# XSLT: xsl:for-each and xsl-choose to retrieve the content of an element and put it somewhere else?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have this XML structure:

```
<book>
    <chap>
        <dev>
            <p>This is some text<apnb id="N1"/>blah blah blah</p>
            <p>...</p>
            <p>...</p>
            <quote>...</quote>
        </dev>
        <defnotes>
            <ntb id="N1">This is the footnote corresponding to the element apnb</ntb>
        </defnotes>
    </chap>
</book>
```

What I would need to do is (since I have almost 900 apbn tags) : for each apbn tag with a certain @id, I would like to display the content of the corresponding ntb tag with the same @id. My guess was to use xsl:for-each select="apbn" with a test inside like xsl:choose. When the @id of the apbn tag is the same @id of the ntb tag, then display the content of the ntb tag. I think it could work but until now I haven't succeeded to implement it.

Many thanks. Flo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best method to resolve cross-references is by using a **[key](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key)**.

You did not specify how your input should look like. In this example, the footnotes will be inserted into the text inside square brackets:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="ntb" match="ntb" use="@id" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="apnb">
    <xsl:text> [</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="key('ntb', @id)"/>
    <xsl:text>] </xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="defnotes"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Test input:**

```
<book>
  <chap>
    <dev>
      <p>This is some text<apnb id="N1"/>blah blah blah</p>
      <p>...</p>
      <p>This is another text<apnb id="N2"/>blah blah blah</p>
      <p>...</p>
      <quote>...</quote>
    </dev>
    <defnotes>
      <ntb id="N1">This is the first footnote</ntb>
    </defnotes>
    <defnotes>
      <ntb id="N2">This is the second footnote</ntb>
    </defnotes>
  </chap>
</book>
```

**Result:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<book>
   <chap>
      <dev>
         <p>This is some text [This is the first footnote] blah blah blah</p>
         <p>...</p>
         <p>This is another text [This is the second footnote] blah blah blah</p>
         <p>...</p>
         <quote>...</quote>
      </dev>
   </chap>
</book>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works but I'm not sure how ! I am quite a beginner with XSLT and I didn't know the use of key. Can you explain exactly what the xsl:key does and how it works? I might need to use it again for some other purposes. Many thanks.